Decomposition of symmetric positive semi-definite matrices
Fix $A\in\mathrm{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix. Then there exists a matrix $M\in\mathrm{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that
\begin{equation}
A=MM^\top+M^\top M.
\end{equation}
For instance, if $X$ is a square root of $A$, then $M=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}X$ works. Can one describe the set of matrices $M$ satisfying this equation? Also, does this decomposition have a name?

You should replace "the square root" by a square root since $A$ is not definite

Also computing the rank of the differential of  $M \mapsto MM^T + M^TM$ will give you some info on the dimension of this subvariety
